# SQL select and count same table

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I'm making a newsletter tool with a table that stores e-mail address's user and email id opened, to calculate total and unique opened for every sent e-mail.

I'd like to show a detailed page with a distinct about e-mail address's user and counting times that the user opened the e-mail.

Example of db table:

```
email_id | user_id | user
----------------------------
 1 | 1 | alpha@domain.com
 1 | 1 | alpha@domain.com
 1 | 1 | alpha@domain.com
 1 | 2 | beta@domain.com
 1 | 3 | gamma@test.org
 1 | 4 | mars@planet.net
 1 | 4 | mars@planet.net
```

Web result:

```
║  User             ║ Times ║
╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ alpha@domain.com  ║    3  ║
║ beta@domain.com   ║    1  ║
║ gamma@test.org    ║    1  ║
║ mars@planet.net   ║    2  ║
```

I tried the following query but it works only for the first row, then it truncates the rest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user, count(DISTINCT user) as counttotal 
FROM newsletter_log 
where email_id = 1
```

Comment: How about `SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS counttotal FROM newsletter_log WHERE email_id = 1 GROUP BY user`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It works! Thank you :) @FelixPamittan

Comment: @Otto, Please accept jarlh's answer below.

Comment: Yep. I have to wait some minutes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`. Use `COUNT(*)` to count.

```
select user, count(*) as counttotal
FROM newsletter_log
where email_id = 1
group by user
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 select user,count(user) as times from newsletter_log where email_id = 1 group by user
```

you dont need to use distinct. just use group by.

Answer (score 1):

Concept is like, you want to get count based on user group. So consider user as group and do the count per group.

```
select user, count(1) as cnt
FROM newsletter_log
where email_id = 1
group by user
```

For Knowledge,you can study various count patterns like count(*),count(1) etc.

Answer (score 1):

To include total:

```
SELECT email, IsNull(User, 'Total'), COUNT(User) [Count]
FROM newsletter_log
WHERE email = 1
GROUP BY email, User
  WITH (ROLLUP)
ORDER BY COUNT(User) DESC
```